# Angular directive second parameter is undefined

Tags: angular

In the directive below, the attribute "directory" is undefined, when passing a variable to it.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCloudDownload]'
})
export class CloudDownloadDirective {
  @Input() directory;

  @Input('appCloudDownload')
  set fileId(value: string) {
    this.cloudService.download(this.directory, value)..... //directory is undefined
  }
```

usage:

```
<img [appCloudDownload]="fileId" [directory]="directory" />
```

but it's ok when passing a string directly:

```
<img [appCloudDownload]="fileId" directory="my-directory" />
```

How to ensure that all directive attributes has their value?

Just one point: Everytime "fileId" changes, it needs to download again.

Comment: can you show when directory property being set in component. May be directive is called before value assigned in directory inside component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a small [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ebnooq) based on your information..

Because I think your Problem is the lifecycle Hook in Angular (using a Input Variable in another Input Variable can be sometimes tricky).

Both your variables should have a value in the ngOnInit() lifecycle Hook.

In my Opinion you have 2 Options:

1. Use ngOnInit() and ngOnChanges() lifecycle Hooks
2. Use ngOnInit() lifecylce Hook for subscribe to a BehaviorSubject, which you call with .next() in your fileId setter.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a setter on your second parameter

```
_directory: string;

@Input() directory;
set directory(value:string): boolean {
  this._directory = value;
}

@Input('appCloudDownload')
 set fileId(value: string) {
  this.cloudService.download(this._directory, value);
}
```

Comment: Nop. Still undefined.